# Cassandra can't find jemalloc package on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, jemalloc

Cassandra 3.11.7 on Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't seem to pick up the jemalloc library?

apt shows:

> libjemalloc2/focal,now 5.2.1-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]

Cassandra logs:

> jemalloc shared library could not be preloaded to speed up memory
> allocations

The same version of Cassandra on Ubuntu 18.04 picks up libjemalloc2 just fine, there a trick to getting it to work on 20.04?

Comment: what is java version used?

Comment: openjdk 1.8.0_265

Answer (score 1):

It might be this issue:

[bin/cassandra" only looks for "libjemalloc.so" or "libjemalloc.so.1" which doesn't match our "libjemalloc.so.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15767)

So then try to create a symlink

```
libjemalloc="$(readlink -e /usr/lib/*/libjemalloc.so.2)"; \
ln -sT "$libjemalloc" /usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.so; \
```